How do I get specific hardware outpit from get-pnpdevice
I am working with refurbished laptops and we are running a custom script to pull specs from the laptops in this script I have the below string to pull Biometrics like fingerprint sensor and Windows hello, the issue with this is that it will say there is Biometric in the laptop regards of which one is there, so we can till if it's fingerprint sensor or windows hello or both.
We would like to fine tune this to only show fingerprint sensor.
Please keep in mind this has to work with the whole script and needs to be as simple as possible.
I have this:
$Biometric = Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object {$_.Class -eq 'Biometric'} | Select-Object -Property FriendlyName | ft -HideTableHeaders | Out-String
if ($Biometric)
{
    $BiometricOK = "Biometric"
}
else { $Biometric = "Not found" | Out-String }

The issue is this pulls both fingerprint and Windows hello, we only need the fingerprint.
When I run this:
Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object {$_.Class -eq 'Biometric'} | Select-Object -Property FriendlyName | ft -HideTableHeaders | Out-String

I get this:
Windows Hello Face Software Device
Synaptics WBDI - SGX

I know it's the Synaptics that is the fingerprint.
If I use this instead:
Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object {$_.friendlyname -eq 'Synaptics WBDI - SGX'} | Select-Object -Property FriendlyName | ft -HideTableHeaders | Out-String

I get:
Synaptics WBDI - SGX

Now I would like to be able to ONLY get:
Synaptics

That way I know it's only the fingerprint sensor.
I tried to experiment with the -split but get an error every time.

Why not specifying the properties you want in the Where-Object like this: Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object {$_.Class -eq 'Biometric' -and $_.FriendlyName -like '*Synaptic*'}   ... ? This way you get only the device you want.


Use Get-PnpDevice's own filtering abilities, and access the .Manufacturer object on the resulting objects.
Get-PnPDevice -Class Biometric -FriendlyName Synaptics* |
  ForEach-Object Manufacturer


Or, if you want to filter by manufacturer (outputs the full Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#ROOT/cimv2/Win32_PnPEntity instance):
Get-PnPDevice -Class Biometric |
  Where-Object Manufacturer -eq Synaptics

